# How to send Image back so that navbar can look transparent in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build Netflix clone, and want the Navbar same as Netflix.

The Navbar is transparent already, but its not visible because the background of navbar is white. Currently I have two components  and  and calling them in App.js .

If I set the image as background through CSS, its working. But what I'm trying to do here is I'm calling the image as a Banner in  component and trying to overlay the  upon  so that the Navbar can look transparent.

Can you someone suggest how to do this?

App.js-

```
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';

function App() {
return (
<div className="App  h-screen overflow-visible">
  <Navbar />
  <Home />
</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js-

```
import React from 'react'
import logo from '../images/netflix-logo-png-2562.png'
import { useScrollPosition } from '../hooks/Navscroll'

const Navbar = () => {
function classNames(...classes) {
return classes.filter(Boolean).join(' ')
}
const scrollPosition = useScrollPosition();

return (

<div className={classNames(scrollPosition> 0 ? 'bg-black' : 'bg-transparent', 'sticky top-0 z-20 h-16 ',)}>
    <nav className=" bg-transparent">
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-9xl px-3 sm:px-6 lg:px-14">
            <div className="relative flex h-16 items-center justify-between">
                <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">
                    {/* <!-- Mobile menu button--> */}
                    <button type="button"
                        className="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white"
                        aria-controls="mobile-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                        {/* <!-- Icon when menu is closed. Menu open: "hidden", Menu closed: "block" --> */}
                        <svg className="block h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5"
                            stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round"
                                d="M3.75 6.75h16.5M3.75 12h16.5m-16.5 5.25h16.5" />
                        </svg>
                        {/* <!-- Icon when menu is open. Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden" --> */}
                        <svg className="hidden h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5"
                            stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                            <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
                    <div className="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center">
                        <img className="h-7 w-auto" src={logo} alt="Your Company" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>

)
}

export default Navbar
```

Home.js

```
import React from 'react'
import billboardImg from '../images/netflix_home_bleach.webp'
import billboardTitle from '../images/bleach_title.webp'

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <>
    
    <div className='home relative'>
      <div className=''>
        <img src={billboardImg} alt="" className='w-screen' />
        <div className='left-gradiant'></div>
        <div className='age_content bg-black text-white absolute flex flex-row justify-items-end right-0 bottom-[35%]'>
          <div className=''>
            <p> U/A 16+</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div className='billboard_detail absolute z-10 w-full h-full top-0 bottom-0  left-0 right-0 '>
        <div className='billboard_detail_container flex flex-col w-[36%] absolute justify-end left-[60px] bottom-[40%] top-0 py-1'>
          <div className="log_and_text w-full">
            <div className='billboard_title py-1'>
              <img src={billboardTitle} alt="" className='w-full ' />
            </div>
            <div className='billboard_description text-white text-xl py-2  '>
              <div className='season_description font-extrabold text-[1.6vw] py-2'>
                <p className=' '>Season 14 coming on 1 August</p>
              </div>
              <div className='synopsis  text-[1.2vw] py-2'>
                <p>After teenager Ichigo Kurosaki acquires superpowers from wounded soul reaper Rukia Kuchiki, the two of them join forces to round up lost souls.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div className="billboard_btn flex flex-row">
              <div className='billboard_play_btn mr-2'>
                <button className='bg-white text-black text-2xl rounded-sm px-8 py-3 font-bold flex flex-row gap-3'><i className="fa-solid fa-play text-3xl pt-1"></i> <span>Play</span></button>
              </div>
              <div className='billboard_info_btn ml-2'>
                <button className='bg-gray-500 text-white text-2xl rounded-sm px-8 py-3 font-bold flex flex-row gap-3'><i className="fa-solid fa-circle-info text-3xl pt-1"></i> <span>More Info</span></button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

css.js

```
.home .left-gradiant {
  background: linear-gradient(77deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), transparent 85%);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 26.09%;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const useScrollPosition = () => {
    const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0)

    useEffect(() => {
        const updatePosition = () => {
            setScrollPosition(window.scrollY)
        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', updatePosition)

        updatePosition()

        return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', updatePosition)
    }, [])

    return scrollPosition
}
```

[Currently navbar looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xlGWF.png)

[I want it to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxhne.png)

I don't want to use the image as a background through CSS, so that I can dynamically change the images .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `position: fixed` instead of `position: sticky` via the `fixed` utility class on the `<Navbar>` root element. This will also "shrink wrap" the element so you would need to apply `width: 100%` via `w-full` to have it be the full width of the screen.

```js
const { useState, useEffect, Fragment } = React;

const useScrollPosition = () => {
  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const updatePosition = () => {
        setScrollPosition(window.scrollY)
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', updatePosition)

    updatePosition()

    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', updatePosition)
  }, [])

  return scrollPosition
}

const Navbar = () => {
  function classNames(...classes) {
    return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
  }

  const scrollPosition = useScrollPosition();

  return (
    <div className={classNames(scrollPosition > 0 ? "bg-black" : "bg-transparent", "fixed top-0 z-20 h-16 w-full")}>
      <nav className=" bg-transparent">
        <div className="mx-auto max-w-9xl px-3 sm:px-6 lg:px-14">
          <div className="relative flex h-16 items-center justify-between">
            <div className="absolute inset-y-0 left-0 flex items-center sm:hidden">
              {/* <!-- Mobile menu button--> */}
              <button type="button" className="inline-flex items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2 text-gray-400 hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white" aria-controls="mobile-menu" aria-expanded="false">
                <span className="sr-only">Open main menu</span>
                {/* <!-- Icon when menu is closed. Menu open: "hidden", Menu closed: "block" --> */}
                <svg className="block h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M3.75 6.75h16.5M3.75 12h16.5m-16.5 5.25h16.5" />
                </svg>
                {/* <!-- Icon when menu is open. Menu open: "block", Menu closed: "hidden" --> */}
                <svg className="hidden h-6 w-6" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" strokeWidth="1.5" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                  <path strokeLinecap="round" strokeLinejoin="round" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12" />
                </svg>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div className="flex flex-1 items-center justify-center sm:items-stretch sm:justify-start">
              <div className="flex flex-shrink-0 items-center">
                <img className="h-7 w-auto" src="https://picsum.photos/50/28" alt="Your Company" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className='home relative'>
        <div className=''>
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/1600/900" alt="" className='w-screen' />
          <div className='left-gradiant'></div>
          <div className='age_content bg-black text-white absolute flex flex-row justify-items-end right-0 bottom-[35%]'>
            <div className=''>
              <p> U/A 16+</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className='billboard_detail absolute z-10 w-full h-full top-0 bottom-0  left-0 right-0 '>
          <div className='billboard_detail_container flex flex-col w-[36%] absolute justify-end left-[60px] bottom-[40%] top-0 py-1'>
            <div className="log_and_text w-full">
              <div className='billboard_title py-1'>
                <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/200" alt="" className='w-full ' />
              </div>
              <div className='billboard_description text-white text-xl py-2  '>
                <div className='season_description font-extrabold text-[1.6vw] py-2'>
                  <p className=' '>Season 14 coming on 1 August</p>
                </div>
                <div className='synopsis  text-[1.2vw] py-2'>
                  <p>After teenager Ichigo Kurosaki acquires superpowers from wounded soul reaper Rukia Kuchiki, the two of them join forces to round up lost souls.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="billboard_btn flex flex-row">
                <div className='billboard_play_btn mr-2'>
                  <button className='bg-white text-black text-2xl rounded-sm px-8 py-3 font-bold flex flex-row gap-3'><i className="fa-solid fa-play text-3xl pt-1"></i> <span>Play</span></button>
                </div>
                <div className='billboard_info_btn ml-2'>
                  <button className='bg-gray-500 text-white text-2xl rounded-sm px-8 py-3 font-bold flex flex-row gap-3'><i className="fa-solid fa-circle-info text-3xl pt-1"></i> <span>More Info</span></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App  h-screen overflow-visible">
      <Navbar />
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<App/>);
```

```css
.home .left-gradiant {
  background: linear-gradient(77deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6), transparent 85%);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  right: 26.09%;
  top: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.3"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```